# How to extract three type of data extrat to a csv file with multiple page in ruby?

Tags: ruby, csv

According to code, three arrays is written csv file in a sheet.

```
i = 0
while i < (name_array.length)
  CSV.open("result.csv", "ab",) do |csv|
    csv << [name_array[i], price_array[i], details_array[i]]
  end
  i += 1
end
```

I desire to be written in a csv file with three sheet and each sheet is compromised by each array. How should I manipulate? Is there any, function of csv library?

Comment: CSV files don't have sheets. Each file is in essence a single sheet, and only one sheet.

Comment: Also instead of `while` try `name_array.length.times do |i|` and that side-steps a lot of the `i += 1` stuff.

Comment: Just to note that is's better to change `while` to `name_array.length.times` as mentioned by @tadman or `name_array.each_with_index do |v, i|`. Also, open file out of cycle and close after or move cycle into block that passed to `CSV.open`